# Snake game tail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working at a 2D Snake Game in Unity.
This is the head of the Snake:

[image: head of snake]

And this is the Extension of the tail of the snake. It is added everytime I eat something:

[image: Extension of the tail of the snake]

I made the head of the snake to move, but my question is how do I move the extensions? I tried to add these extensions as childs to the head , but when i rotate the head, it rotates the all extensions at the same time, but I want to rotate one extension at a time like a chain. I am using a C# Script

```
   if (position == 1 || position == 3) {
                if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
                    position = 2;
                    rotation=90;
                    transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler(0,0,rotation);

                } 

else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
                position = 4;
                rotation=270;
                transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler (0,0,rotation);
            }
        } else if (position == 2 || position == 4) {
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
                position=1;
                rotation=0;
                transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler (0,0,rotation);
            }
            else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
                position=3;
                rotation=180;
                transform.rotation=Quaternion.Euler (0,0,rotation);
            }
        }
        if (position == 1)
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime,Space.World);
        else if (position == 2)
            transform.Translate (Vector3.up* movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime,Space.World);
        else if(position==3)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left*movementSpeed*Time.deltaTime,Space.World);
        else if(position==4)
            transform.Translate (Vector3.down*movementSpeed*Time.deltaTime,Space.World);
        int i;
        for (i=1; i<extensions.Count; i++) {
            extensions[i].transform.position=extensions[i-1].transform.position;
            extensions[i].transform.rotation=extensions[i-1].transform.rotation;
        }
```

Comment: Hi :) Can you post the relevant source code so that others can take a look at it?

Comment: Are you trying to do the traditional version of Snake, where you are restrained to a grid, or are you trying to do this with free-roaming? I.e. how is the snake allowed to move.

Comment: @zstewart traditional, only 4 directions

Comment: @Bogdan15 In the traditional grid-constrained version, it suffices to move the head one square, then move each successive tail segment into the square previously occupied by its predecessor, whenever you step forward one square.

Answer (score 0):

maybe with an arraylist.
And then on position 0 you set the parent (snakehead)
1 you set the child,2 next child, and go on.
And for each movement every frame.
You know where each part was previous and you set that for each Child.
When you updated the position for each part, you can set the positions of the object to the values of the array.

You Cannot set the parent property because you would get unexpected behavior.

Please excuse me if I made a typo and short answer. (I'm on my phone)

Answer (score 0):

You should check it in movement with a list. While it keeps moving: if {it eats food then instantiate a tail}, else {the list should follow the head}. Check this link: http://coffeebreakcodes.com/complete-projects/2d-snake-game-unity3d-c/

Answer (score 0):

If you put each of the sections (including the head) in a `List`, you can take each section in `Update ()` (or wherever you call your movement function) and move it to the position and rotation of the section immediately preceding it in the list. This way, all you have to control the movement of directly is the head; the following sections will move with exactly the same path.